# Infinite scroll with Backbone and Firebase

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, infinite-scroll, firebase

I'm trying to use the [infiniScroll.js](https://github.com/joneath/infiniScroll.js) in my main view of the Backbone app, but it's not working. This is the JSFiddle with all the code: http://jsfiddle.net/swayziak/9R9zU/13/

And this is the view where I'm trying the infiniScroll.js

```
app.BookListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '.feed',
    initialize: function() {
        this.render();
        this.listenTo( this.collection, 'add', this.renderBook );
        this.infiniScroll = new Backbone.InfiniScroll(this.collection, {success: this.renderBook});
```

I don't know if the problem is related with the infiniScroll module or with another part of the code. I'm new to backbone, so every help is welcomed (including another way to do an infinite scroll in the app).

Thanks.

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't include the plugin so there is no `Backbone.InfiniScroll` to `new`.

Comment: Thanks for noticing that. I've updated the fiddle in the question with the plugin included

Comment: I don't really see how this involves Firebase. You have declared a variable called Firebase, which is a defunct URL, but you haven't actually included the firebase.js script or employed it anywhere. Additionally, infiniScroll uses Collection.fetch, which you haven't declared a URL for (or replaced with a Firebase related method). Your example is completely dysfunctional.

Comment: It now says `SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'`. I'd recommend stripping out everything that isn't related to your scrolling problem and make sure your example loads.

Comment: Without everything related with the scrolling the example works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/swayziak/9R9zU/15/

Comment: Hi Kato, can you explain me better how I replace the Collection.fetch with a Firebase related method? Thanks

Comment: Any suggestion replace the Collection.fetch with a Firebase related method?

Comment: You can use the Firebase/Backbone bindings to replace Backbone.Collection with Backbone.Firebase.Collection and sync all the data: https://github.com/firebase/backfire

Comment: Hi Anant, thanks for the reply. I've done that, but the infinite scroll doesn't work. When I arrive at the end of the scroll the console says:  "Fetch called on a Firebase collection, ignoring." I was thinking in trying something with the queries startAt, endAt or limit. Do you have some suggestion?